# How Can I add a Check for Updates Menu Item in the OS X Application Menu?

Tags: java, macos, menu, menuitem

On OS X, it is customary for applications that have a "Check for Updates…" menu item to have it in the application menu like so:

[image: Check for Updates in Application Menu]

However, I'm not sure how to do this in Java. Using the `com.apple.eawt` extensions I can add some items to the application menu:

```
Application application = Application.getApplication();

//Register About Menu
application.setAboutHandler(new AboutHandler() {

    @Override
    public void handleAbout(AboutEvent arg0) {
        //Display an about dialog
    }

});

//Register Preferences Menu
application.setPreferencesHandler(new PreferencesHandler(){

    @Override
    public void handlePreferences(PreferencesEvent arg0) {
        //Display a preferences dialog
    }

});
```

However, there doesn't seem to be a generic `Application.setApplicationMenuHandler()` or something of the sort that will let me add an arbitrary menu to the application menu. So how can I add a Check for Updates menu item, or any menu item for that matter?

Comment: I am facing this same problem with SWT too, and would dearly love to find a solution.

Comment: @Thunderforge, I'm behind a curve a bit (ok, nearly 4 years) but I also cannot find what I'm looking for in com.apple.eawt even in JDK 1.8. Did you find something better than putting CfU in the Help menu?

Comment: @jeff6times7 I never did find a solution and it doesn't look like there is one unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### There is no way to do this in Java

The `com.apple.eawt` package was replaced with [new methods for the `Desktop` class](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) in Java 9. This would have been the logical location for something like this, but no such method exists.

I have not seen any third party libraries that allow this and have doubts that it is even possible. So I'm going to throw in the towel and say that it can't be done. Would love to see someone publish another answer proving me wrong though.